# How to harvest a Slicer Selection

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I hope you can help me with this one.

I want to harvest the maximum value of a slicer I have in a Power BI panel.
I tried some solutions I found around here, but none of them worked.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9nlqfz7l9m1f49/Screenshot%202019-04-27%2011.39.36_LI.jpg?dl=0

So as shown in the pictured attached, I would like that the column "Slicer Max" should be equal to the maximum value of the slicer "Mês", ignoring any other filter applied to the panel or the table visualization.

Follows attached also the pbix file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s78uxevo5aelho4/Plano%20de%20Trabalho.pbix?dl=0

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In your matrix visual you are taking the sum of a calculated column which refers to a measure.

A calculated column cannot be dynamically responsive to a filter since it is only computed once per data load.

Instead of taking the sum of the calculated column you created, simply use the measure instead.

```
Mês Max fplano = MAX(fPlanodeTrabalho[Mês Fim])
```

or if you want to make sure there isn't anything else affecting that selection from that table:

```
Mês Max fplano = 
    CALCULATE(
         MAX(fPlanodeTrabalho[Mês Fim]),
         ALLSELECTED(fPlanodeTrabalho)
    )
```